# Как сделать фильтр элементов в React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть стейт, в который пишутся выбранные фильтры:

```
  state = {
    filters: [],
  };
```

Есть список элементов:

```
const json = [
    {action : true, new : true, name : 'Морський'},
    {action : true, new : false, name : 'Дольче Віта' },
    {action : false, new : false, name : 'Спекотний сезон' },
    {action : false, new : true, name : 'Уікенд' },
]
```

Как отфильтровать элементы по выбранным фильтрам? Стейт с фильтрами может выглядеть так: `filters ["new", "action"]`

Answer (score 0):

**Ответ:**

```
const result = json.filter(x => filters.every(y => x[y]));
```

```js
const filters = ["new", "action"];
const json = [
  { action: true, new: true, name: "Морський" },
  { action: true, new: false, name: "Дольче Віта" },
  { action: false, new: false, name: "Спекотний сезон" },
  { action: false, new: true, name: "Уікенд" }
];

const result = json.filter(x => filters.every(y => x[y]));

console.log(result)
```